# :after and :before CSS pseudo elements hack for Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, pseudo-element

I am using `:after` and `:before` CSS pseudo elements and it is working fine in **Internet Explorer 8**, and all modern browsers but it is not working fine in **Internet Explorer 7**. Are there known hacks to work around this in **Internet Explorer 7**?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

with any pure CSS hack it's not possible.

Use IE8.js http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

It has support for this. http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html

test page also there

after - http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/after.html

before - http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/before.html

**Edit after 1st comment**

You can just keep this js for IE6 and 7. other browser will not read it.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

And if you are already using jQuery in your project than you can use this plugin

**jQuery Pseudo Plugin**

http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/pseudo/

Comment: Thanks for reply.This is the way we can solve this problem. I didnt want to load any external java script file. So is there any other way to do this.

Comment: @saorabh - I've updated the answer. with pure CSS I think it's not possible for IE6/7. If you can provide the code it can be useful to understand the scenario

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with before and after, it may be possible to use CSS only. Answer with Gist posted below.

Comment: Question to Jitendra...I added The Jquery Pseudo on my jquery...working good but when i added on the my server it works well on homepage (IE7) url-homapage/images/image.jpg....but when i go to another page the pseudo does the path like this: url-homepage/about/images/image.jpg...how can i prevent this..I assume its the pattern on the js..

Answer (score 52):

I was using IE8.js (http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) in a project and I had to remove it because it blocked IE7 between 10/15 secs.

To mantain the content generated with :after and :before pseudo-elements, without IE8.js, I did the following:

```
   .tabs {
     *zoom: expression( 
          this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",
          this.appendChild( document.createElement("small") ).className="after"
         );
   }

   .tabs:after,
   .tabs .after {
     content: '';
     display:block;
     height:10px;
     width:100%;
     background:red;
   }
```

I prefer this way rather than with javascript, because this will keep all selectors in the same place :)

Comment: executed using js when?? how?? :S

Comment: The one thing that doesn't seem to work if you are targeting an `<img>` tag with this. The expression doesn't run for some reason.

Comment: <img> tag doesn't work because this is putting the after inside the tag (appendChild), which you can't for things like img.

Answer (score 4):

To before and after you can use this:

```
.tabs {
    *zoom: expression(
        this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",
        this.insertBefore(
            document.createElement("div"),
            this.childNodes[0]
        ).className="before",
        this.appendChild(
            document.createElement("div")
        ).className="after"
    );
}

...

.tabs::before, .tabs .before {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    float: left;
}
.tabs::after, .tabs .after {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #c0c;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a pure CSS hack that works, sort of. It's black magic but is sometimes handy when used scarsely.

It's explained here: <del>http://nanobox.chipx86.com/blog/2006/07/before-and-after-in-ie7-and-below.php</del> http://web.archive.org/web/20080706132651/http://nanobox.chipx86.com/blog/2006/07/before-and-after-in-ie7-and-below.php

**HTML fragment:**

```
<div id="container">
 <!-- -->
 <div class="mainContent">
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <p>Blah blah</p>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container:before
{
 background: url("corners-top.png");
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 24px;
}

#container .mainContent:after
{
 background: url("corners-bottom.png");
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 28px;
}
```

**IE-specific stylesheet:**

```
#container *
{
 background: url("corners-top.png");
 display: list-item;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 list-style: none;
}

#container .mainContent
{
 background: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.25;
}

#container .mainContent *
{
 background: url("corners-bottom.png");
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
}

/*
  Now, still in the IE-specific stylesheet, remove the styles for all
  element descendants of .mainContent. Refer to each element by tag name.
*/

#container .mainContent p, #container .mainContent div, (And so on...)
{
 background: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.25;
}
```

Comment: @bazmegakapa Here's the [wayback machine archive.](http://web.archive.org/web/20080706132651/http://nanobox.chipx86.com/blog/2006/07/before-and-after-in-ie7-and-below.php)

Comment: @d4n3 Thanks. Imported the most important parts from the archive.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS expressions to do this. For example you could plug a ♣ symbol via:

```
expression(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage="none",this.innerHTML = '♣'+this.innerHTML)
```

I wrote an article about this on Smashing Magazine, see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/19/styling-elements-with-glyphs-sprites-and-pseudo-elements/

Comment: css expression are black list at yslow rules

Comment: I think using IE7 would be a greater cause of slowness. CSS expressions are only supported by IE, and they were dropped in IE8. If you are concerned about speed, get a better browser. If you want to support ancient clients, use slow hacks.

Comment: @Jeremy You shouldn't make slower browsers even slower. Your users are not your enemies.

Comment: Correct! That's why we're supporting IE7 in the first place.

Comment: This method seems to create multiple characters in IE7, as if IE7 is looping the content being set with `this.innerHTML`. Anyone having this same problem with this code?

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/), it has a core detect for "CSS Generated Content".

You can then fill in the missing `:before` or `:after` using JavaScript. For example:

```
.selector:before, .selector-before {
    content: "Hello, world!";
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery to insert generated content directly into the DOM:

```
if (!Modernizr.generatedcontent) {
    $('.selector').prepend('<span class="selector-before">Hello, world!</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When needing support for :before and :after I use the following gist that I wrote. It's pure CSS (to the point were you just write CSS) but does include a CSS expression. Works in most cases.

https://gist.github.com/2362483

```
/* =============================================================================
    CSS Declarations
   ========================================================================== */

/* ==|== The Standard Way =================================================== */

.foo::before {
  /* ...css rules... */
}

.foo::after{
  /* ...css rules... */
}


/* ==|== The IE Way =================================================== */
/* NOTE: a comma separated IE & Standard rule won't work.               *
 * IE doesn't understand ::before or ::after & ignores the declaration  */

.lt-ie9 .foo:before,
.lt-ie8 .foo .ie-before {
  /* ...css rules... */
}

.lt-ie9 .foo:after,
.lt-ie8 .foo .ie-after {
  /* ...css rules... */
}


/* =============================================================================
    IE6 & IE7 polyfills
   ========================================================================== */

.lt-ie8 .foo {
  zoom: expression(
    this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",

    /* ::before polyfill - creates <i class="ie-before"></i> */
    this.insertBefore( document.createElement("i"), this.firstChild ).className="ie-before",

    /* ::after polyfill - creates <i class="ie-after"></i> */
    this.appendChild( document.createElement("i") ).className="ie-after"
  );
}
```

Comment: css expression are black list at yslow rules

Comment: point taken...but the OP is looking for 'hacks' to solve the issue in IE.