# Is there a faster way to give ":before" and ":after" selector support in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

My design currently calls for a lot of `:before` and `:after` selectors. IE7 does not support these selectors so, after a little digging, I am now using [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) (the IE8 version).

Whilst it does work, there is a noticeable lag (approx 15-20 seconds).

Can anyone recommend a faster alternative so that I can use the `:before` and `:after` psudo-element selectors in IE7?

Comment: They are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-classes-hack-for-ie-7

Comment: There really shouldn't be a *15-20 seconds* lag. Do you have a test page online?

Comment: @mnicky That is what I am currently using. I would like to find an alternative as it is causing a lot of lag.

Comment: @thirtydot No, this is still in development.

Comment: If you have *zillions* of `:before` and `:after`, the cause of the problem could be IE7's slowish JavaScript engine - if this is the case, I think **you're out of luck** - IE7.js is probably as efficient as you're going to get. Can you try to recreate the problem on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)? That way we can try to spot if anything can be improved.

Comment: @thirtydot I have a page with only one :before and :after and that is taking about 7-9 seconds, so I think you are right about it being the number of selectors I'm using.

Comment: IE7.js is doing a LOT in bringing the browsers up to speed, however I am only after the selectors. I am not proficient enough with js to strip out everything I do not need, but maybe someone somewhere already has? @thirtydot if you post your previous comment I shall accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> If you have *zillions* of `:before` and
>   `:after`, the cause of the problem could
>   be IE7's slowish JavaScript engine -
>   if this is the case, I think you're
>   out of luck - IE7.js is probably as
>   efficient as you're going to get.

and:

> @thirtydot I have a page with only one
>   :before and :after and that is taking
>   about 7-9 seconds, so I think you are
>   right about it being the number of
>   selectors I'm using.

**IE7 :(**

Answer (score 2):

I use this CSS hack in css:

```
.button {
 *zoom: expression( 
      this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1",
      this.insertBefore( document.createElement("div"), this.childNodes[0] ).className="before",
      this.appendChild( document.createElement("div") ).className="after"
     );
```

}

...and later simply:

```
.button:before, 
.button .before{
    ...
}
```