# Use after: and before: selectors in versions 6 and 7 of Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser

I am using the nice style of the wizard mentioned in [this blog](http://techbrij.com/798/stylish-asp-net-wizard-control-horizontal-sidebar-on-top)
but unfortunately it does not work well in the IE, because as mentioned in the blog:

**For browsers that don’t support :after/:before/ nth-child, the code will not work.**

So is there any way to fix this problem to make work well in the IE browser.

FYI, the CSS is:

```
#wizHeader li .prevStep
{
    background-color: #669966;
}
#wizHeader li .prevStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#669966 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep
{
    background-color: #C36615;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep:after
{
    border-left-color: #C36615 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep
{
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#C2C2C2 !important;
}
#wizHeader
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wizHeader li
{
    float: left;
}
#wizHeader li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
    background: brown; /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#wizHeader li a:after
{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#wizHeader li a:before
{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#wizHeader li:first-child a
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#wizHeader li:last-child
{
    padding-right: 50px;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover
{
    background: #FE9400;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover:after
{
    border-left-color: #FE9400 !important;
}
.content
{
    height:150px;
    padding-top:75px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    font-size:48px;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-classes-hack-for-ie-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The before and after css elements should work in ie8 and up.

For IE7 you can use something like Use the [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) hack to add after & before pseudo element support.

I would recommend using a conditional statement to include the file such as;

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    insert script here
<![endif]-->
```

For IE6, I personally would not bother and just degrade gracefully.

Another option is [to use ie-css3.js](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/enable_css_pseudo-element_selectors_in_internet_explorer_with_ie-css3.js/).