# Support of :after in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, pseudo-element

Long story short, I want to add an absolutely positioned pseudo element after another element, so I simply use the `:after` pseudo element in my stylesheet. This works like a charm, except in IE7. I should think that `:after` is supported in IE7, no? The [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) hack used in Boilerplate works fine, so why not in my example?

When I look at the CSS in the style inspector, it does seem to print it out, so it **seems** to me that it understands it, but I can't see the generated element nonetheless. Am I missing something?

```
.myclass:after { 
   content:"";
   display:table;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background:#f7f7f7;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:-1px;
   z-index:0; }
.myclass > div {
   position:relative;
   z-index:10; }   
.myclass { 
   z-index:1;
   position:relative; }
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/264gq/)!

Comment: [Here is the same question with the answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [no support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15) for `:before` and `:after` in IE7, there are other options that you can use like [IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Comment: That's a pretty heavy script to load, just for this. I just find it strange, that the clearfix hack works fine, then.

Comment: @Nix Which is strange because not even in the microsoft site it is stated that it is supported in IE7, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoelements

Comment: @Nix just took a look at the clearfix hack you mentioned, this is why its working in IE > `/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}`

Comment: Well, yes, but I thought that is to fix the hasLayout bug specifically? I'm not sure why the clearfix should work otherwise, I just assumed something was bundled with Boilerplate (like Html5shiv or Modernizr) made it work. The IE8.js completely messes up my layout, however, so I'm just going to add the element manually. *sigh* Thanks anyway.