# What is the alternative for using :after and :before in IE7

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I am using pseudo classes and they work fine everywhere except IE7. I would like to know if there is any way to make them work in IE7.

Comment: I think you should show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link on stackoverflow and the same question, somehow I am sure you'll find the answer you want here.

[:after and :before css pseudo elements hack for IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect user-agent on the server and output different HTML to different browsers.

For PHP, you can use [Browser.php](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) (for example), or simply look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable

Other than that - only Javascript, sorry.

EDIT: Simplest way (no JS coding needed) - is to use Selectivizr - http://selectivizr.com/

It's the CSS3 emulation library for IE6-8

Comment: can you just through some more insight into your first option please

Comment: For the first option: what do you use on your server side? PHP, C#, Ruby, Python, Perl?

Comment: php is how I would like to know

Comment: Here, have a link for PHP and for Javascript. Personally I prefer the JS version - it's A LOT simpler.

Answer (score 0):

No can do...

if it is absolutely necessary to utilize those pseudo elements in that browsers, you'll probably have to load a js file to correct the problem: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/