# Font-family CSS3 in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, css, fonts, internet-explorer-7, font-face

For some reason my website causes IE to render in "document mode IE7".
I have replaced the sprites and image icons on the page with a font version.
Unfortunately, the font-face css does not work in this browser. 
When I switch the "document mode" to IE8 or IE9 in IE's developer tools, the icons show as intended.

I do not understand why IE7 does not show the icons. As far as I know, it should be possible for it to use the font.

As you can see in the code, I have used the font files and css defintions from fontello.com.

Here is the style sheet that I use to show the icons:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
 font-family: 'fontello-postbit';
 src:url(/includes/fonts/fontello-postbit.eot);
 src:url(/includes/fonts/fontello-postbit.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
 url(/includes/fonts/fontello-postbit.woff) format('woff'),
 url(/includes/fonts/fontello-postbit.ttf) format('truetype'),
 url(/includes/fonts/fontello-postbit.svg#fontello-postbit) format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;
 font-style:normal;
}
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: 'fontello-postbit';
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size: 120%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:1em;
  margin-right:0.2em;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0.8;
/* fix buttons height, for twitter bootstrap */
  line-height: 1em;
/* Animation center compensation - magrins should be symmetric */
/* remove if not needed */
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  speak: none;
}
.icon-star:before { content: '\2605'; } /* '?' */
.icon-star-empty:before { content: '\2606'; } /* '?' */
.icon-flag:before { content: '\2691'; } /* '?' */
.icon-attention:before { content: '\26a0'; } /* '?' */
/* ... etc ...*/
.icon-user:before { content: '\1f464'; } /* '\1f464' */
</style>
```

EDIT: Duh - I just noticed that fontello offers a css workaround for IE7 themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements are not recognized by IE7.

You might try some of these solutions, if its critical:
[after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7)

Or you could disregard IE7.