# How to make css two borders?

Tags: css, colors, border

I was wondering what you guys think is the easiest way to get a double border with 2 colors around a div? I tried using border and outline together and it worked in Firefox, but outline doesn't seem to work in IE and that's sort of a problem. Any good ways to go about this?

This is what I had but outline does not work with IE:

```
outline: 2px solid #36F;
border: 2px solid #390;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS double border (2 colors) without using outline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735569/css-double-border-2-colors-without-using-outline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
 .border
    {
        border:2px solid #36F; 
        position:relative;
        z-index:10
    }

    .border:before 
    {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        top:2px;
        left:2px;
        right:2px;
        bottom:2px;
        border:2px solid #36F
    }
```

Comment: thanx i can made tripple borders using the `:after` too

Answer (score 4):

Just use 2 divs

```
<div style="border: 2px solid #36F">
    <div style="border: 2px solid #390">
        Text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fpCAf/

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities:

1. border + outline borders , *IE fails* .
2. border-image . you need to produce the image (waste of time ?) *IE 9 fails*
3. pseudo elements , fast and easy: no extra markup, image and gradient can be use.*IE8 should handle it, but not the gradient*
4. borders + box-shadow *IE9 should handle it, filter for older IE is not good looking*
5. multiple box-shadows can be drawn inside and outside, great to give
   depht effects on borders, it follows border-radius too.*IE9 should handle it, filter for older IE is not good looking*
6. background image and gradient *IE9 fails on gradient*

... Left? if you want less than IE8 : wrap 2 elements to draw 2 basic borders