# How to do two border upon one div tag by css or by css3?

Tags: html, css

I m developing a html/css template for my client. Here has a post div which class name is: single_post_box.
On this div slyle is like bellow:

```
single_post_box{
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}
```

Now my client want, there will two border. 1st border color will:#eaeaea & 2nd border color will: #dddddd.
How can I do that.

Comment: use `box-shadow` and `border` together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use pseudo-elements to do so

```
.double {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.double:before {
    background: none;
    border: 4px solid #666;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
```

you can check this answer [CSS: Double border with different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463904/css-double-border-with-different-color)

Answer (score 2):

just add this to your style,i think you want a div with different colour

```
box-shadow: red 0px 0px 0px 2px, green 0px 0px 0px 4px;
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can add the following to get the same effect

```css
div{

border :1px dashed red;
outline : 3px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div> this is me </div>
```