# Create Border In CSS that is inverted and doesnt add to the outside

Tags: css

I was wondering how to create a border that doesnt add to the outside of a div but works it's way inside

```
#MenuBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #5a5b54;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: -10px;
    border: 10px solid black;

}
```

tried using a margin although it didn't work

Comment: and would you care to share what's wrong with your script? or are we supposed to spend half an hour to find out what your problem is?
Imagine you run a car shop and someone comes, gives you a photograph of a third of a car and says: how can I make this car drive again?

Comment: oh sorry, didn't even think about it

Comment: You can either (1) use `box-sizing: border-box`; (2) use a box-shadow as a border substitute and combine that with padding so that the box-shadow does not overlap with your content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, there are two solutions to your problem:

## Solution 1: Use `border-box`

`box-sizing: border-box` will force the element's width and height computation to take into account border widths.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#MenuBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #5a5b54;
    z-index: 1;
    
    border: solid 10px black;
    
    /* Calculate border as part of width and height */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="MenuBox">
#MenuBox
</div>
```

## Solution 2: Use `box-shadow` as a border replacement

Using an inset box-shadow with a spread of `10px` will mimic the effect of having a border, but this time it being within the bounds of the element. This effect is useful [if you want to have multiple borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463904/double-border-with-different-color/19464014#19464014), but otherwise stick to solution #1.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#MenuBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 2.5%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #5a5b54;
    z-index: 1;
    
    /* Use box-shadow */
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px black;
    
    /* Use padding to offset content */
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="MenuBox">
#MenuBox
</div>
```