# css create border line with specific effect

Tags: css

[image: border line]

How can I create the above effect in css border?

Comment: What effect would that be? What HTML are you working with, where did you get stuck? Did you look at the [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) property? Or SVG? Did you do any research? Where did that lead you, how did it not work or satisfy your expectations?

Comment: If it was such easy, I would not ask! Can't you see there is a 3D depth effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box shadow for additional border effect. For more detailed examples please check [Double border with different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463904/double-border-with-different-color)

```
  <hr> 
  <style>
    body {
      background: #1f1f1f;
    }

    hr {
      border: none;
      height: 2px;
      background: #000;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #404040;
    }
  </style>
```