# Multiple -webkit-box-reflect on one image left and right

Tags: html, css, webkit

So,

I was looking into expanding images to make them fill the width, given a certain height.

I decided I wanted to do something along the lines of reflecting the image both left and right.

However, I can only get it to apply to one side of the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LukIbK7.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.image {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.image img {
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-reflect: left 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hum7uo2y/)

I've also tried using :before as directed in a similar post (to do with multiple borders) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735569/css-double-border-2-colors-without-using-outline)

If there is also another solution, please inform me (without having to actually edit the images).

Essentially, I wanted the result css to be:

```
.image img {
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-reflect: left 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
    -webkit-box-reflect: right 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
}
```

To achieve:

[image]

But obviously it will just overwrite it.

Comment: can you draw the final result (what you want to achieve)?

Comment: @Tambo http://i.imgur.com/KwgcjZm.png essentially

Comment: Given that the right side is a mirror of the image, rather than my bad mspaint skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the only thing remotely similar to what I want to create is by using some dodgey jquery that duplicates the img.

```
$("img").clone().appendTo(".image")
.css("-webkit-box-reflect", "left 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)))")
.css("margin-top", "-100%");
```

It's so messy though: http://jsfiddle.net/hum7uo2y/1/

EDIT:

Found a way, didn't think about reflecting a div instead.

HTML is now:

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="reflect">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LukIbK7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css is now:

```
.image {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.reflect {
    width:50%;
    margin:auto;
    -webkit-box-reflect: right -2px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)))
}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-reflect: left 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(transparent), color-stop(20%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
}
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hum7uo2y/3/