# How I can create a border with double color?

Tags: html, css

I need a line with two color combinations. Can anyone help me make a line like the line in the attached image?

[image]

Please review the image I attached and help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Use pseudo elements (:before , : after) to achieve what you want

Comment: @LuisP.A. How I can use pseudo elements is their any example you have please share..

Comment: @ArslanAli: Is that meant to be two colors on same line (or) the red slightly above gray like in the image?

Comment: What do you need it for? Is it for an active status for a menu item?

Comment: visit following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14735816/4944490

Comment: No its simply a horizontal line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use pseudo element to create the 2nd border, simple demo follows.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* or -1px for covering it */
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @pangloss code is working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  position:relative;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%)
```

```html
<div></div>
```