# How to make pseudo elements work while browser is in compatibility mode?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles

```
 .divClassGreen{

       border-bottom:4px solid  white;   
       position: relative;
}
.divClassGreen:before{


       border-bottom:5px solid  white;   
       content: '';
        position: relative;
         top: -6px;
        right: -6px;
        bottom: -6px;
        left: -6px;
}  
.divClassGreen:after{


       border-bottom:5px solid  green;  
       content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: -11px;
        right: -2px;
        bottom: -9px;
        left: -2px; 

}
```

This is my css , but the before and after are not working when my IE 8 is in compatibility mode. Is there any solution for the same?

Comment: i assume compatibility mode tries to display pages as if they are rendered in older versions. from this http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/ it says that pseudo elements are not supported in ie7.

Comment: is there any fix for the same?

Comment: there is a similar question i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Modernizr JavaScript library to detect browsers that don't support `:before` and `:after` (such as early versions of IE), and then use JavaScript to emulate those selectors. To download only the part of the library that you need, you can go to [this link](http://modernizr.com/download/#-generatedcontent-teststyles) (the appropriate checkbox is already selected). Then, you can add two extra classes to your CSS that mimic the styles of `.divClassGreen:before` and `.divClassGreen:after`:

```
.divClassGreen:before, .divClassGreenBefore {
    /* blah */
}  
.divClassGreen:after, .divClassGreenAfter {
    /* more blah */
}
```

Finally, use JavaScript to add empty `div` tags before and after `.divClassGreen` (empty because you have `content: ''`) that have the styles `.divClassGreenBefore` and `.divClassGreenAfter`:

```
//If the browser doesn't support generated content (:before and :after)
if (!Modernizr.generatedcontent) {

    var divClassGreen = document.getElementsByClassName("divClassGreen"); //returns a NodeList

    //Create the equivalents of :before and :after
    var divClassGreenBefore = document.createElement('div');
    var divClassGreenAfter = document.createElement('div');

    //Add the appropriate classes
    divClassGreenBefore.className = 'divClassGreenBefore';
    divClassGreenAfter.className = 'divClassGreenAfter';

    //Iterate through the NodeList, which adds the element before and after each .divClassGreen
    for (i = 0; i < divClassGreen.length; i++) {

        //Adds before
        divClassGreen[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divClassGreenBefore, divClassGreen[i]);

        //There's no insertAfter, so imitate it by using insertBefore on the hypothetical (next) sibling of divClassGreen
        divClassGreen[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divClassGreenAfter, divClassGreen[i].nextSibling);
    } 

}
```