# Bottom content hide with shadow in ie7

Tags: css, css-float

I want to display following output:

[image]

Following line code is working perfectly in all browser except in ie7. In ie7 it looks:
[image]

So can you tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
<div id="parent" class="shadow">
<div style="margin: 10px 20px 30px 20px; min-height: 300px; word-wrap: break-word;
  Low cost enclosed temperature control; UL Class 2 low voltage sensor circuit with var...                  
</div>
<table id="seemore" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <a href="#" id="" title="See More">
          <span class="SeeMoreText">See More</span> </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

#parent
   {

```
float: right;
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #e3e3e3;
margin-top: 30px;
position: relative;
max-height: 420px;
```

}

#seemore
{

```
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 250;
*z-index:250;
bottom: -20px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:visible;` to `#parent`

```
#parent{
 float: right;
 width: 250px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
 max-height: 420px;
 overflow:visible; /*<--*/
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you or not?

Comment: No it is still not working. I have already used this attribute but I was forgot to mention here.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it is the clearfix issue. There are lot of things to avoid it.
Either you can try this.

```
/* For modern browsers */
        #parent:before,
        #parent:after {
            content:"";
            display:table;
        }

        #parent:after {
            clear:both;
        }

        /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
        #parent {
            *zoom:1;
        }
```

or, you can use the following technique discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).
or, if still not worked out, try [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181884/after-and-before-css-pseudo-elements-hack-for-ie-7)